# iOS: how to get correctly battery level

Tags: ios, ios5

I have tried to get correctly battery level. But that value is not like value in status bar of iphone.

by code use UIDevice:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];

[[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryLevel];
```

please someone help me! I need get correctly battery level that like in status bar imdimatery.

Comment: Did you actually read the documentation? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/batteryLevel

Comment: Possible dumplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807295/how-to-get-real-time-battery-level-on-ios

Answer (score 10):

Well the Apple docs say this:

> Battery level ranges from 0.0 (fully discharged) to 1.0 (100% charged). Before accessing this property, ensure that battery monitoring is enabled.

So your code should be like this:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
float batteryLevel = [[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryLevel];

//This will give you the battery between 0.0 (empty) and 1.0 (100% charged)
//If you want it as a percentage, you can do this:

batteryLevel *= 100;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: :( I did it. But that return 5% in earch step. 100%->95%->90%... But that not correctly like value in status bar. please help me another way. I used some soft in ios5, them get correctly value. I think we can get... but i don't how to do. Sr my english very bad

Comment: You can't. Without a Jailbreak you can't get *exact* battery percents

Comment: I know its old but there is this app on the app-store called Battery Doctor and it is showing exact values for battery level and charging status. Any idea on how it does that?

Answer (score 3):

**Swift** version to get the battery level:

```
UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
let batteryLevel = UIDevice.current.batteryLevel * 100
```

Comment: I got the battery level -1 even after setting isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true.
how come?

Comment: Use this code only for real devices, the simulator will return "-1".