# Check Battery Level iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I just started Swift and I have been looking for a way to check the battery level.  I found [this resource](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/batteryLevel) and have been playing around with it but for some reason can't seem to get it to work.

I wasn't quite sure how to go about fixing this. Any ideas?

Comment: you must also post the issue that you are facing

Answer (score 151, accepted):

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1**

First just enable battery monitoring:

```
UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
```

Then you can create a computed property to return the battery level:

> Battery level ranges from 0.0 (fully discharged) to 1.0 (100%
> charged). Before accessing this property, ensure that battery
> monitoring is enabled. If battery monitoring is not enabled, battery
> state is UIDevice.BatteryState.unknown and the value of this property
> is –1.0.

```
var batteryLevel: Float { UIDevice.current.batteryLevel }
```

To monitor your device battery level you can add an observer for the  `UIDevice.batteryLevelDidChangeNotification`:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(batteryLevelDidChange), name: UIDevice.batteryLevelDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

---

> Battery level ranges from 0.0 (fully discharged) to 1.0 (100% charged). Before accessing this property, ensure that battery monitoring is enabled.
> If battery monitoring is not enabled, battery state is UIDevice.BatteryState.unknown and the value of this property is –1.0.

---

```
@objc func batteryLevelDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    print(batteryLevel)
}
```

---

You can also verify the battery state:

```
var batteryState: UIDevice.BatteryState { UIDevice.current.batteryState }
```

---

```
case .unknown   //  "The battery state for the device cannot be determined."
case .unplugged //  "The device is not plugged into power; the battery is discharging"
case .charging  //  "The device is plugged into power and the battery is less than 100% charged."
case .full      //   "The device is plugged into power and the battery is 100% charged."
```

---

and add an observer for `UIDevice.batteryStateDidChangeNotification`:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(batteryStateDidChange), name: UIDevice.batteryStateDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

---

```
@objc func batteryStateDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    switch batteryState {
    case .unplugged, .unknown:
        print("not charging")
    case .charging, .full:
        print("charging or full")
    }
}
```

Comment: Superb Answer..!!

Comment: Not working in my case. Receiving -1.0 always

Comment: Swift Syntax changed a bit for Notifications:
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(batteryLevelDidChange), name: UIDevice.batteryLevelDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(batteryStateDidChange), name: UIDevice.batteryStateDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

Answer (score -3):

> var batteryLevel: Float { get }

Make sure that battery monitoring is enabled first =)

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/batteryLevel)