# Smartphone Battery Usage

Tags: android, ios, performance, battery, energy

I am trying to find a way to get the battery consumption in absolute value.
For example, currently there are many apps that shows the battery consumption in percentage (x% used by Y app). Is there any way to find the absolute value of battery consumed and value left? Let's say when battery is fully charged the value is F power unit and when it is used it reduces to X Power Unit. So the percentage could be said as (X/F * 100) % battery used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check Battery Level iOS Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475506/check-battery-level-ios-swift)

Comment: Multiply the percentage with the battery capacity?

Comment: Have you looked at the [BatteryManager API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html), specifically at the CAPACITY constants? And BATTERY_PROPERTY_CHARGE_COUNTER?