# How to check the Battery Health on iOS 10 and above version.

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, iokit, batterylevel

I'm using IOKit framework to check the battery health (not battery level), and I'm able to get the exact data as coconut battery app shows. Can someone let me know will App Store allow the app to publish if we use IOKit.

Comment: Have a look at this thread: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/51595
Not giving a final answer either, but might be interesting for you.

Comment: refer below link:-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475506/check-battery-level-ios-swift I hope it help you,Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check Battery Level iOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475506/check-battery-level-ios-swift)

Comment: @VDPurohit Thanks for your feedback, I don't need the battery level. I want to check the Battery Health state (which will give the wear level of battery).

Comment: @PraveenB Did you find any solution to find Batter health (not battery level)