# how to fetch battery usage and level of my devices in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I want to get battery usage data from my iPhone. I used `UIDevice currentDevice.batteryLevel` code, but its returning -1.0000 in NSLog value.

Anyone please help me?

One more question, can I able to fetch other app battery usages in my app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get real time battery level on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807295/how-to-get-real-time-battery-level-on-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must enable batteryStatus notification (in appDelegate.m for instance):

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    ...
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
    // Now, the system will post UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification notification when batteryStatus (or connection) will change

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(batteryStatusDidChange:) name:UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    ...
}
```

Then, you can check battery level calling:

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].batteryLevel;
```

that will return you a value between 0.0 (0% chareg) and 1.0 (100% charge).

Without calling first `setBatteryMonitoringEnabled`, battery state will return `UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown` and the value of this property is –1.0. (from docs).