# How can I get info about iPhone/iPad battery in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How can I get battery cycles count and wear rate or at least max capacity, so that my app could be accepted?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get battery level

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].batteryLevel
```

this is how you get battery state

```
UIDeviceBatteryState currentState = [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryState;
```

this is the enum of `UIDeviceBatteryState`

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIDeviceBatteryState) {
    UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown,
    UIDeviceBatteryStateUnplugged,   // on battery, discharging
    UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging,    // plugged in, less than 100%
    UIDeviceBatteryStateFull,        // plugged in, at 100%
} __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I'm looking for(( I'm interested whether there is a way to get maximal battery capacity

Answer (score 0):

**Objective C:**

```
  [[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
    UIDevice *myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];

    [myDevice setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
    double batLeft = (float)[myDevice batteryLevel] * 100;
    NSLog(@"%.f",batLeft);


NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f%%", batLeft]);
```

**Swift:**

```
try
{
    UIDevice.CurrentDevice.BatteryMonitoringEnabled = true;
    _Battery.Level = (int)(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.BatteryLevel * IOSBatteryLevelScalingFactor);
    _Battery.State = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.BatteryState;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ExceptionHandler.HandleException(e, "BatteryState.Update");
    throw new BatteryUpdateException();
}
finally
{
    UIDevice.CurrentDevice.BatteryMonitoringEnabled = false;
}
```

Find reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807295/how-to-get-real-time-battery-level-on-ios-with-a-1-granularity)