# How Can I Display Battery Percentage for iOS 7?

Tags: objective-c

I need help. I'm trying to make a battery monitor and I can't figure out how too. I'm not sure how any of UIDevice works...

Comment: You should include what you have you have tried so far in your question. If you haven't tried anything yet, don't post a question.

Answer (score 0):

See the related post below.  I also hate to add that you should probably search stackoverflow first to see if someone has already answered your question.

[iOS: how to get correctly battery level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801523/ios-how-to-get-correctly-battery-level)

Comment: Okay, I did that but how would I display that in a label?

Comment: Not to sound harsh, but you should probably just do some iOS tutorials first.  Then move on to battery monitoring.  Check out these tutorials: http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials