# iOS: How can I get the battery usage from code?

Tags: ios

I want to get the battery usage data from code.
How can I do that?

[Data what I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBR4E.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Code will be look like below

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
float batteryLevel = [[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryLevel];

//This will give you the battery between 0.0 (empty) and 1.0 (100% charged)
//If you want it as a percentage, you can do this:

batteryLevel *= 100;
```

### Resource Link:

[iOS: how to get correctly battery level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801523/ios-how-to-get-correctly-battery-level)

Comment: Thanks. 

But I want to get time that I spend for the specific app.

For example:

Safari: 2.7 hours on screen 56%
Instagram: 29 min on screen 10%